# Ubuntu 16.04 external drives mounting read only

Tags: mount, fstab, external-hdd

All of my external drives mount to

/media/usb0

instead of

/media/username/driveid

If I stop and restart with disks they mount correctly.

My fstab is

UUID=6... /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
UUID=b.. /Data-work               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1

Comment: is fstab entries for the external?

Comment: No, I was just showing it as I can't see anything in it that I can see is causing this